# Find a function that applies under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I have function$ | x-1|$. I want to find function $f(x),g(x)$ that are continous and differentiable except 0 that $f(g(x))=|x-1|$. A choice for functions like this $f(x)=\sqrt{x},g(x)=(x-1)^2$. Do you know any other non-radical functions?

Comment: But $f(x)$ is even undefined when $x < 0$. How differentiable would you want?

Comment: @Yuki.F Well, in my opinion, the fact that $f$ is not defined everywhere is not a problem since $f \circ g$ is well-defined. But there **is** a problem in the fact that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible, because if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable everywhere, then $f \circ g$ is also differentiable everywhere.

Here the problem comes from the fact that $f$ *is not* differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Ok We remove the derivability condition. Thank you

Comment: If you remove the differentiability condition at 0, you have so much solution, the simplest example is $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=x-1$.

Comment: Thanks except this solution you have any functions?

Comment: $f(x)=|\ln(x)|$ and $g(x)=\exp(x-1)$ ;) This is basically the same example, for every bijection $h$, the two functions $f \circ h$ and $h^{-1} \circ g$ work, it gives you lots of examples.